# Not getting desired output. Is there something inherently wrong in the logic?

Tags: c, arrays, logic

the input depicts no of tests followed by size of input array followed by the array and the output either gives -1 or the square of the largest prime in the given array.
I am providing the code and the expected and actual output along with sample standard input used.

```
standard input:
3
5
1 4 6 8 10
3
2 2 9
2
156 13

expected output | getting
-1                -1
4                  4
169               -1


#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int test,size;
int i,j;
scanf("%d\n",&test);
while(test>=1){
    scanf("%d\n",&size);
    int data[size],factors=0,max=0;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        scanf("%d ",&data[i]);
        for(j=1;j<=data[i];j++){
            if(data[i]%j==0){
                factors+=1;
            }
        }
        if((factors==2) && (data[i]>max)){
            max=data[i];
        }
    }
    if(max>=2){
        printf("%d\n",max*max);
    }else{
        printf("%d\n",-1);
    }
    max=0;
    test-=1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok debugged and got the answer. Factors needs to be initialized inside the next for loop.